# Universal Task List

Tags: tasks, aggregation

I suspect I am over-complicating this issue. At least it seems like such an obvious need that I would expect an obvious, pre-existing solution.

Specifically, we want the user to be able to automatically see all of his tasks from all of his main task lists in all sites visible on the main ("Home") site of the site collection. I don't see anything OOB like this in SharePoint Foundation. I noticed a QuerySiteCollection property in 2007, but I am not sure if this is what I want or what the implementation would be in 2010 SharePoint Foundation.

There are three major points to the above:
1. Aggregate the items from task lists in the site collection into a single, universal task list.
2. Aggregate the items from the MAIN task list of all sites in the site collection (i.e. not  all tasks from all lists in each site, just all tasks from the main task list of each site). 
3. Automatically aggregate the tasks (i.e. Don't require the user (or anyone) to manually specify the main task list of each site in the site collection; if a new site is created, the main task list items are au

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably after is [rollups with the Data View and SPDataSource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/04/24/spdatasource-and-rollups-with-the-data-view.aspx)

> I’ll give a brief overview of the SPDataSource control, as well as
>   cover a pretty popular question: How do I create a view that rolls up
>   data from across my site collection?

See also

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx

http://spquerydemo.codeplex.com/